# $facet of mongodb returning full sorted documents instead of count based on match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a documents as below

```
{
    _id:1234,
    userId:90oi,
    tag:"self"
},
{
    _id:5678,
    userId:65yd,
    tag:"other"
},
{
    _id:9012,
    userId:78hy,
    tag:"something"
},
{
    _id:3456,
    userId:60oy,
    tag:"self"
},
```

i needed response like below

```
[{

tag : "self",
count : 2
},
{
tag : "something",
count : 1
},
{
tag : "other",
count : 1
}
]
```

i was using $facet to query the documents. but it is returning entire documents not the count. My query is as follows

```
db.data.aggregate({
    $facet: {
        categorizedByGrade : [
            { $match: {userId:ObjectId(userId)}},
            {$sortByCount: "$tag"}
        ]
    }
})
```

Let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't need to use `$facet` for this one - facet is when you really need to process multiple aggregation pipelines in one aggregation query ([mongoDB $facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html)), Please try this :

```
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{$project :{tag :1, _id :0}},{$group :{_id: '$tag',
count: { $sum: 1 }}}, {$project : {tag : '$_id', _id:0, count :1}}])
```

**Explanation :**

`$project` at first point is to retain only needed fields in all documents that way we've less data to process, `$group` will iterate through all documents to group similar data upon fields specified, While `$sum` will count the respective number of items getting added through group stage in each set, Finally `$project` again is used to make the result look like what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the correct records using facet, please have a look at below query

```
db.data.aggregate({
    $facet: {
        categorizedByGrade : [
      {
       $sortByCount:"$tag"
      },
      {
        $project:{
           _id:0,
          tag:"$_id",
          count:1,
         
        }
      }]
    }
})
```